# Selenium install Marionette webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, firefox-marionette

I have this issue with firefox version 47 https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/2110

So, i have tried to add Marionette web driver to fix it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

But:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['binary'] = '/Users/myproject/geckodriver-0.8.0-OSX'
```

returns error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'wires'
>   executable needs to be in PATH.
>
> Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute
>   'process'" in >
>   ignored

selenium==2.53.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the firefox binary capability you're setting points to the *firefox* binary, not the marionette driver binary. You need to add `/Users/myproject/geckodriver-0.8.0-OSX` to your path as follows:

Open a terminal and run this command

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myproject/geckodriver-0.8.0-OSX
```

Answer (score 5):

I [ran into this issue](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/90) and can confirm that `firefox_capabilities['binary']` should point to the Firefox binary, not to GeckoDriver.  The Python example in the [Mozilla WebDriver documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) has been clarified on this topic.

Comment: firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

firefox_capabilities['binary'] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla 
Firefox\firefox.exe'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)

Hi Raymond, I'm also having trouble. I added what appears to me to be all the fixes for the problems the articles listed however I'm still getting the same wires executable needs to be in path error.

Comment: The error says wire executable needs to be included in path, but I do have reference to where the firefox exe is in my environment path variable.

Comment: @user3042850 If you are using 64-bit Windows, then try the executable at https://sny.no/e/geckodriver1.exe instead - most tutorials point you at the 32-bit executable (recommendation taken from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/74#issuecomment-226927179)

Also bear in mind that if you are on Windows you will need to rename the driver binary to "wires.exe", not "wires" :-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other two answers, you probably don't want to change the `PATH` system wide since you need it only when running the tests. A way to have the right `PATH` only when you need it is to set it in code:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'path/to/dir/containing/geckodriver/'
```

A simpler workaround would be to simple move the `geckodriver` binary to the directory you already have in your path:

```
mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin
```