# How to solve the Python Selenium error which

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to use the selenium to deal with some website using JavaScript codes. To begin with,I use simple example as below

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')

browser.quit()
```

While this even does not work. The error msg is shown as below. I think I may missed something in selenium or something else. Could you bring me some light on this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rnie/webdriver-tutorial-1x.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 145, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

I checked the `"geckodriver.log"`, and it shows following error messages:

```
1479623778556   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:49723
1479623778625   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path /tmp/rust_mozprofile.WMDGNONHQTud
1479623778628   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser /usr/bin/firefox
1479623778641   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:35691
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

Answer (score 0):

Pl check path or if you are on Linux have a look for http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/can't-open-display-no-protocol-specified-using-gdm-4175462031/

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium 3.0 release, Firefox Selenium driver has been updated to a new driver called Marionette or "geckodriver". This is a separate binary on your system.

See how to use geckodriver with Python: [Selenium install Marionette webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808643/selenium-install-marionette-webdriver)

If you want to use old Selenium driver, version 2.x:

- [Install your Python packages properly using virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808643/selenium-install-marionette-webdriver)
- `pip install "selenium<3"`
- Downgrade your Firefox to version 45 or add `firefox` version 45 binary to your ``PATH``` environment variable

Answer (score -2):

**These days Firefox is not doing much good with Selenium web-driver i can suggest you to use Chrome Driver instead**

> Download the chrome driver and extract the file. set the chrome driver path in the Environment path and then try with same code by replacing **Firefox() to Chrome()** 
>   or follow below code....

```
from selenium import webdriver

Path = ("c://chromedriver//chromedriver.exe")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(path)
#eliminate above two steps if the path is set in Environment variable 

browser = webdriver.Chrome() 

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')

browser.quit()
```

Comment: Yes, I changed into chrome and my problem here solved.